# How can we further specify the objectproperty in an ontology without making very detailed has...type relationship?

Tags: sparql, ontology, semantic-web, protege

I am a bit lost. This is what I like to model in an ontology:

`A isConnectedTo B via ConncetionTypeClass1.`

`A isConnectedTo D via ConncetionTypeClass2.`

`E isConnectedTo F via ConncetionTypeClass3.`

For A and (B and D), I can create two classes that would have an object property isConnectedTo. But how can I specify the type of connection for each pair (i.e., ConncetionTypeClass)?
I mean,  I like to avoid creating a properties such as  `isConnectedViaConnectionType1 ,  isConnectedViaConnectionType2 etc`.

Comment: either you use properties per connection type (which you don't want) or you have to use an n-ary relation which then has 3 generic properties e.g. `source`, `target`, `type` . (I omit the 3rd way via annotation/reification here because it's sometimes too limited for peoples use-cases)

Comment: Thanks! I will read about the n-ary relationships. Can we model them using protege?

Comment: yes: https://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-n-aryRelations/